# Bootable USB Drive Not Appearing During Installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu onto a bootable external hard drive, usb 3.0, but during the final stages of installation where one chooses the *device for boot-loader installation* the device does not appear. This is being performed on a Dell Alienware R4 and it is booting from legacy mode with nomodeset turned on (as I get a black screen with a mouse cursor otherwise).

The only options presented under *device for boot-loader installation* are to install onto my internal C and D drives and does not show an option for the external, yet the drive appears in *Disks* as a cdrom. I have even tried switching usb ports to no avail.

[Here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00KWHJY7Q/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) is the external that I am using, and below are the configurations made in Rufus:

[Rufus Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBbc3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a separate physical drive, like a USB flash drive, as the bootable medium for installing Ubuntu. A small 4 or 8GB pendrive is sufficient.
Boot from this drive and install to your External hard drive.

This problem might be because you are using the same external drive for both.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you, thank you.